# Problema para insertar datos en una BBDD desde PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas a todos!

Pues mi problema es el comentado en el título. Desde un formulario en php estoy intentando que los datos que recoja los inserte en una bbdd, y no consigo encontrar el fallo.

Primer documento HTML que se llama "index.html":

```html
<doctype HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Tarefa UD03</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css"> -->
  <style>

   body{

    margin: 0 auto;
   }

   table{

    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
   }


   h1{

    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }

   th{

     font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
   }

   td{

    font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    }

   table{

    margin: 0 auto;
   }

   #contenedor1{

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 105px;
    background-color: #F5F6CE;
    border: 2px solid black;
   }

   .caja_text{

    font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
   }

   .anho{

    font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
   }

   #enviar{

    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 580px;
    font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
   }
   
  </style>
 </head>
 <body style='background-color: #E6E6E6;'>
  <h1>CICLOS</h1>
  <form name='formulario' id='formulario' method='post' action='conexion_bd.php'>
   <div id='contenedor1'>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Nome:</th>
      <td><label for='textfield'></label>
      <input type='text' name='nombre' id='nombre' class='caja_text' placeholder='Ex: Xoan' maxlength='15'></td>
      <th>Apelido 1:</th>
      <td><label for='textfield'></label>
      <input type='text' name='apellido1' id='apellido1' class='caja_text' placeholder='Ex: Rodríguez' maxlength='15'></td>
      <th>Apelido 2:</th>
      <td><label for='textfield'></label>
      <input type='text' name='apellido2' id='apellido2' class='caja_text' placeholder='Ex: Pérez' maxlength='15'></td>
      <th>Ano Inicio:</th>
      <td><label for='textfield'></label>
      <input type='text' name='anho_in' id='anho_in' class='anho' min='' max='' placeholder='Ex: 2014'></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>Ciclo:</th>
      <td>
       <select name='nom_ciclo' id='nom_ciclo'>
        <option>Desarrollo de Apps Web</option>
        <option>Desarrollo de Apps Multiplataforma</option>
        <option>Admin. de Sistemas Informáticos</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <th>Curso:</th>
      <td><label for='textfield'></label>
      <input type='radio' name='curso' id='curso' class='caja_text' value='1'>1º
      <input type='radio' name='curso' id='curso' class='caja_text' value='2'>2º</td>
      <th>Grupo:</th>
      <td>
       <select name='grupo' id='grupo'>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
   <input type='submit' id='enviar' name='enviar' value='Enviar este formulario'/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Segundo documento que se llama "conexion_bd.php".

Este es el código HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Tarefa UD03</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css"> -->
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        table {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        h1 {
            margin-top: 100px;
            margin-left: 600px;
            font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        th {
            font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        td {
            font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        table {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #contenedor1 {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 105px;
            background-color: #F5F6CE;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        .caja_text {
            font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        .anho {
            font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #enviar {
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-left: 580px;
            font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        #atras {
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-left: 640px;
            font-family: "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style='background-color: #E6E6E6;'>
    <h1>CICLOS</h1>
    <form name='formulario' id='formulario' method='post' action=''>
        <div id='contenedor1'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome:</th>
                    <td>
                        <label for='textfield'></label>
                        <input type='text' name='nombre' id='nombre' class='caja_text' placeholder='Ex: Xoan' maxlength='15'>
                    </td>
                    <th>Apelido 1:</th>
                    <td>
                        <label for='textfield'></label>
                        <input type='text' name='apellido1' id='apellido1' class='caja_text' placeholder='Ex: Rodríguez' maxlength='15'>
                    </td>
                    <th>Apelido 2:</th>
                    <td>
                        <label for='textfield'></label>
                        <input type='text' name='apellido2' id='apellido2' class='caja_text' placeholder='Ex: Pérez' maxlength='15'>
                    </td>
                    <th>Ano Inicio:</th>
                    <td>
                        <label for='textfield'></label>
                        <input type='text' name='anho_in' id='anho_in' class='anho' min='' max='' placeholder='Ex: 2014'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ciclo:</th>
                    <td>
                        <select name='nom_ciclo' id='nom_ciclo'>
                            <option>Desarrollo de Apps Web</option>
                            <option>Desarrollo de Apps Multiplataforma</option>
                            <option>Admin. de Sistemas Informáticos</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <th>Curso:</th>
                    <td>
                        <label for='textfield'></label>
                        <input type='radio' name='curso' id='curso' class='caja_text' value='1'>1º
                        <input type='radio' name='curso' id='curso' class='caja_text' value='2'>2º</td>
                    <th>Grupo:</th>
                    <td>
                        <select name='grupo' id='grupo'>
                            <option>A</option>
                            <option>B</option>
                            <option>C</option>
                            <option>D</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' id='atras' name='atras' value='Atrás' onclick='history.back()' />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

y este el código php:

```
<?php

session_start();

$db_conexion = "localhost";
$db_usuario  = "root";
$db_pass     = "";
$db_nombre   = "ciclos";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_conexion, $db_usuario, $db_pass, $db_nombre);

if (!$conexion) {

    die("Erro de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apel1  = $_POST["apellido1"];
    $apel2  = $_POST["apellido2"];
    $anho   = $_POST["anho_in"];
    $ciclo  = $_POST["nom_ciclo"];
    $curso  = $_POST["curso"];
    $grupo  = $_POST["grupo"];

    if ($nombre == "" || $apel1 == "" || $apel2 == "" || $anho == "" || $ciclo == "" || $curso == "" || $grupo == "") {

        echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro.')</script>");

    } else {

        mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, anho_inicio, nom_ciclo, curso, grupo) VALUES ($nombre, $apel1, $apel2, $anho, $ciclo, $curso, $grupo)");

        //mysqli_query($query);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Están en el mismo fichero? Si no es así deberías llamar al fichero .php en el action de tu formulario.

Comment: que fallo te da?

Comment: Sí, tengo el html y el php en un único fichero. Y el fallo que me da es que básicamente no me inserta los datos del formulario en la bbdd.

Comment: @Jopimar si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es probable que el error este en que en el `INSERT` estas pasando valores `string` y no has incluido `comillas`.

Prueba hacer este cambio:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios 
(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, anho_inicio, nom_ciclo, curso, grupo) VALUES 
('$nombre', '$apel1', '$apel2', '$anho', '$ciclo', '$curso', '$grupo')");
```

//

Ten en cuenta que:

> [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php): Retorna **FALSE** en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, *mysqli_query()* retornará un objeto [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php). Para otras consultas exitosas de *mysqli_query()* retornará **TRUE**.

Para saber si dio error y porque, deberías modificar tu script de la siguiente forma:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, anho_inicio, nom_ciclo, curso, grupo) VALUES ($nombre, $apel1, $apel2, $anho, $ciclo, $curso, $grupo)");
if ($resultado === false) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
  die();
}
```

Lectura recomendada:

- [Inyección de SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)
- [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Vaya, pues sí que era el error que comentas tú arriba. Arreglado entonces. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes.

- No entiendo porqué le tienes puesto al `submit` una llamada a un método JavaScript.
- Estás esperando que llegue una variable en `$_POST` llamada "enviar" que nunca va a llegar porque no la envías.

Si cambias el valor del atributo `name` del `submit` a "enviar" funcionará (siempre que tus credenciales de conexión a base de datos sean correctas).

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme. Ahora lo que hice es poner un único html con el formulario y en el action que te lleve al archivo php. Y parece ser que funciona porque en el else pongo un echo y lo imprime, pero sigue sin insertar los datos en la bbdd.