# No se insertan los datos mediante mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola tengo un problema no se me insertan los datos mediante *mysqli*
este es mi script

```
  <div id="New-message">
    <div class="m-header">
      <p> <b>New message</b> </p>
      <span class="close" onclick="closemessage()"><i class="icon fas fa-window-close"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="m-body">
      <form method="post" >
        <input type="text" list="user" id="username" onkeyup="checkuser()" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Buscar Usuario" value=""><br>
        <!--Data List -->
        <datalist id="user"></datalist>
        <textarea class="form-control input-message-new" name="message" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder=""></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-message"  value="Enviar"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="m-footer">

    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  $host = "localhost";
  $userdb = "pag";
  $pass = "pag";
  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $userdb, $pass, $userdb) or die("ERROR!");
  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $sender_name = "AzuraNetwork";
    $resiver_name = $_POST['username'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    $q = 'INSERT INTO message(sender_name, resiver_name, message_txt, date_time)
    VALUES ("'.$sender_name.'","'.$resiver_name.'","'.$message.'","'.$date.'")';
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    if ($r) {
      echo "Message Sent";
    }else {
      echo "Error";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

estoy tratando de hacer un envió de formulario desde el mismo `index` a una tabla `messages`, ademas me estoy guiando de este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUZgjM7fqlw para hacerlo pero siempre que envío el formulario este me lanza el `else` "ERROR", ademas de que la pagina se refresca automáticamente.

ademas esta es mi tabla en la base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `resiver_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `message_txt` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Mencionas que: *en el `ELSE` me lanza un error*, ¿puedes por favor adjuntar dicho error?

Comment: Me lanza el valor error osea me muestra El mensaje error y no el mensaje enviado y en mi base de datos no incerta los datos

Comment: El user y la db es la misma

Comment: Me parece que el error es que el campo `id` de la tabla `message` no es `AUTO_INCREMENT` (_o lo has omitido en la pregunta_). Puede que el contenido de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35783/16597) te ayude a encontrar el error.

Answer (score 2):

Realiza la inserción de los VALUE de la siguiente manera.

```
$q = ("INSERT INTO message(sender_name, resiver_name, message_txt, date_time)
VALUES ('$sender_name','$resiver_name','$message','$date')");
```

Te sobran todos los "" y puntos.
Los puntos sirven para concatenar, pero estamos haciendo inserciones en este caso, no juntando cadenas.

Como segundo punto, deberías poner el "id" de la base de datos en AutoIncremental, para que te rellene con valores automáticamente de manera ascendente (1,2,3,4...).

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: sigue lanzándome el `else{echo "Error";}` y mi id ya es AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 0):

Si la tabla la creaste tal cual pusiste el código tu error es que el campo no es autoincrementable (que por cierto tampoco es Primary key lo cual usaras probablemente ya que usas innoDB) pero si es not null, así que si no mandas un valor a la columna no hará la inserción prueba mandando un valor para el id

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el siguiente:
Al tener la PK como no autonumerica, esta esperando que se la insertes con un valor, cosa que no haces.
Para solucionarlo 2 posibilidades.

1. Modifica el campo en la BD y ponlo con autoincrement.
2. Inserta el valor de la PK en la query.

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto:

```html
$q = "INSERT INTO message (sender_name, resiver_name, message_txt, date_time) 
VALUES ('".$sender_name."','".$resiver_name."','".$message."','".$date."') ";
```

Explicación:
Cambia la orientación de las comillas dobles para encerrar el inicio la sentencia sql, las comillas sencillas para los parámetros de tipo string

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero seria mejor si agregas una explicación sobre el código que agregaste. Responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad. Revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hecho! Espero sea de ayuda mis comentarios